# PD controller tuning for flexible joint robotic arm

Tags: control, robotic-arm, pid

I am trying to tune the gains of my PD controller for a single axis flexible joint robot. The controller output is the motor torque. My question is: how can i tune the PD gains if the output (torque) is limited (i.e. the controller output is followed with saturation in Simulink).

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question?  Do you mean the torque always at max?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I mean how I can tune my PID in the way that the torque will not exceed its maximum for high amplitudes (position amplitudes). I wish I am more clear now, if not I will elaborate more :)

Comment: Frequency domain methods can't give you guarantees that your actuator limits are not attained. What you ask for is simply not possible. What you could do is to determine the largest set in state space that you expect your robot arm to operate in and then find gains that satisfy your actuator constraints for every state in that set. I considered the reference here as a state.

Comment: @FelixCrazzolara Thank you very much for your answer